# How to Save Laravel rest Api logs into db

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-5

I want to save all api logs in db.
For example whenever a api gets hit, its request and response get saved in a table.

Is there settings in Lavavel to enable logs of Rest apis into db.

For example in codeigniter:
Request param logs as :
a:12:{s:13:"session_token";s:20:"OiCtWkqBLm6ScaSHOmQR";s:12:"Content-Type";s:16:"application/json";s:13:"cache-control";s:8:"no-cache";s:13:"Postman-Token";s:36:"0d13fe2e-9986-4ef2-ba46-8207dd28cd44";s:10:"User-Agent";s:20:"PostmanRuntime/7.1.1";s:6:"Accept";s:3:"*/*";s:4:"Host";s:9:"localhost";s:6:"cookie";s:81:"PHPSESSID=ho1oa4gjll59u4vq9usct3lev7; ci_session=ruttt4i5144hob6feq3mrv080nh2n74o";s:15:"accept-encoding";s:13:"gzip, deflate";s:14:"content-length";s:2:"19";s:10:"Connection";s:10:"keep-alive";s:7:"user_id";i:13;}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to build something yourself, terminable middleware is a great solution in Laravel. This type of middleware is executed after all the heavy work is done (request & reponses handled, etc.).

Add a new model to store your LogEntries in. Create your migrations, etc. This is basis Laravel stuff I will not explain... :-)

Then, to start off with the middleware, create a middleware class like this:

```
$ php artisan make:middleware RequestLoggerMiddleware
```

Add a body to the new class:

```
class RequestLoggerMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $logEntry = new LogEntry();

        $logEntry->attribute = VALUE;
        $logEntry->attribute = VALUE;
        $logEntry->attribute = VALUE;
        $logEntry->attribute = VALUE;

        $logEntry->save();
    }
}
```

Add the middleware to your Kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    RequestLoggerMiddleware::class,
    ...
];
```

In the Middleware you can add tons of stuff to your attributes. The injected reponse and request have a lot of information in them:

- request start time >> date('Y-m-d H:i:s', LARAVEL_START)
- URL >> request->fullUrl()
- request HTTP method >> $request->method()
- request body >> json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
- request header >> $request->header();
- ip >> $request->ip()
- status code >> $response->getStatusCode()
- request body >> json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

BTW this is an EXAMPLE of a code structure you could use, to give you an basic idea about the solution. Obviously, you need to add the correct attributes to the model, the migrations, etc. But I am sure you can handle that part...

And: inject the Model in the constructor instead the above example... :-)

Comment: I think json_encode can be used instead of the json_encode you made in the last request and response or $request->getContent(); available?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option in laravel for this. So you need write custom code for this checkout at https://sergeyzhuk.me/2016/07/30/laravel-logging-to-db/