# How to save HTTP request data and user data into a database in Laravel 7+

Tags: php, laravel, database, postgresql, request

As the title says I want to know how to save HTTP request data and user data into my database. I am using Postgres.

I google around a bit and found an answer such as [How to Save Laravel rest Api logs into db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696251/how-to-save-laravel-rest-api-logs-into-db) but it is around 3 years old so I am not sure how much things have changed with Laravel. I am still pretty much a noob at Laravel, so I was hoping I could get some help on this.

My current idea is to try to get my request data and save it directly to my database, but I am unsure of how to implement this. I looked into Monolog as well but couldn't find anything that would be of help.

This is a snippet from my migration file.

```
$table->id();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('method');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('body')->nullable();
            $table->string('received_at');
            $table->string('ip');
            $table->string('agent')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
```

Comment: have your tried  this approach ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696251/how-to-save-laravel-rest-api-logs-into-db

Comment: Yeah, I have looked into this method however I am unsure of how current the information is.